# Deny usage of == on Groovy (or change its behavior)

Tags: java, gradle, groovy

How can I deny the usage of `==` on Groovy files (or make it works exactly as equals?)

To deny the usage, I prefer any solutions like:

- A command-line parameter on compile or even runtime
- An annotation to disable it
- An environment variable

In worst case, I'll try to do it using Gradle, searching for the string `==` on `*.groovy` and block the build if it found any occurence. I can try Sonar also, but I prefer a built-in feature of Groovy (if such thing exists, of course)

Any solution that makes == works exactly as equals is great also.

---

**Reason**:

I have a big project and realized that some issues happens because `==` is NOT the same as `equals()`. The operator `==` uses the `compareTo()` if the class extends `Comparable`, ignoring the value of `equals()` and `hashCode()`. Reference: http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/latest/html/documentation/#_behaviour_of_code_code

---

UPDATE 1

**Use case**:
A use case is: suppose you have Dogs objects with fields: `id` and `name`. To check equality, we need to use **id**, because id is unique. However, to sort dogs alphabetically by name, I need to use `compareTo`, checking the `name` field. And because 2 dogs can have the same name, Groovy is thinking that `dog(id:1, name:'rex')` is the same as `dog(id:2, name:'rex')`

Comment: I don't have a solution ready, but before I spend time researching it, did you check if this is doable with sonarqube? It looks like the kind of things a code analyzer should be good at.

Comment: A good initiative, but almost 50 years too late...

Comment: Hmm, making `compareTo` incompatible with `equals` is asking for trouble.

Comment: @Henry true "It is strongly recommended, but not strictly required" by the contract of `compareTo`. I have to wonder in which case that's a useful property, though.

Comment: Which Groovy version?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca `BigDecimal` is an example where they are incompatible (and I was hit by that already).

Comment: @thokuest The version is Groovy 2

Comment: I think the SecureASTCustomizer will help you with this. You can check the operator of all binary expressions and emit an error for == (or any other operator of your choosing).

Comment: compareTo should be compatible with equals. In your Usecase, compareTo should return 0 if and only if the id and name check.